# Need help about nginx reverse proxy (and jenkins ?) configuration

Tags: docker, jenkins, configuration, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to setup a basic mockup (for training) with 2 docker containers :

- One with nginx
- One with jenkins

nginx is used as a reverse container (the next step wil be https frontend).
jenkins is supposed to be publicly accessible as www.devportal.org:90/ci

I have partially succeeds. I mean that I can access it with the given address. But ...

- When I try to connect with the admin user, I get the login page. But when filling the user / password, I am redirected to http://www.devportal.org/ci/.
- If I add the port to this address, I obtain the instance home page, connected as the admin user.
- When I select the manage page, I see a warning message saying that my reverse proxy configuration is broken.
- Besides, when going to configure system, the page is displayed but it never finishes loading.

I tried various configuration for nginx, but none of them gave me the correct result.
The Jenkins Location URL is set to the instance address known by nginx.
As far as both are within containers linked to a dedicated docker network where jenkins is known as jenkins_ci, the address is http://jenkins_ci:8080/ci/.
And if I run :
`docker exec nginx_revproxy wget http://jenkins_ci:8080/ci/`
I actually get the home page.

Here is my nginx configuration (in : /etc/nginx/conf.d/reverse_proxy.conf)

```
# Reverse proxy configuration for one jenkins server
# Nginx listen public traffic on port 90 and forward to jenkins container address on port 8080
server {
        listen 90;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

        location ^~ /ci/ {
                proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_pass http://jenkins_ci:8080/ci/;

                # Fix the "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_read_timeout  90;
                proxy_redirect      http://jenkins_ci:8080/ http://www.devportal.org:90/;
                # Required for new HTTP-based CLI
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_request_buffering off;
        }
}
```

When getting an error page at connexion I see this on nginx container log

`172.17.0.1 - - [19/Jul/2019:12:32:04 +0000] "GET /ci/ HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "http://www.devportal.org:90/ci/login?from=/ci/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0" "-"
2019/07/19 12:32:04 [error] 7#7: *40 "/usr/share/nginx/html/ci/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /ci/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.devportal.org", referrer: "http://www.devportal.org:90/ci/login?from=/ci/"`

On the jenkins container log I also have :
`Jul 19, 2019 2:18:25 PM hudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor getTestForReverseProxySetup
WARNING: http://www.devportal.org/ci/manage vs. http:`

Additional information
With nginx conf:

```
server {
        listen 90;
         server_name www.devportal.org;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

    location ~ "^/static/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\/(.*)$" {
        #rewrite all static files into requests to the root
        #E.g /static/12345678/css/something.css will become /css/something.css
        rewrite "^/static/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\/(.*)" /$1 last;
     }

        location /ci/ {
        proxy_pass      http://jenkins_ci:8080;
        proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        # Fix the "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_read_timeout  90;
        proxy_redirect      http://jenkins_ci:8080/ http://www.devportal.org:90/;
            # Required for new HTTP-based CLI
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_request_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Connection ""; # Clear for keepalive
    }
}
```

and

```
<jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration>
  <adminAddress>[my mail address]</adminAddress>
  <jenkinsUrl>http://www.devportal.org:90/ci</jenkinsUrl>
</jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration>
```

in

```
jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration.xml
```

I make some progress regarding the error message in jenkins log :

```
Jul 22, 2019 11:59:35 AM hudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor getTestForReverseProxySetup
WARNING: http://www.devportal.org/ci/manage vs. http://www.devportal.org:90/ci/manage
```

Now, I only loose the port number (I lost the whole domain name before).
*Note that it is the same with or without proxy_redirect.*

Comment: I have read the related [jenkins page](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy) eliminating stuff related to https. 
I also see the various answers around nginx reverse proxy here ... but have not been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Jenkins URL should be set to what your user see as standing in description:

```
Optionally specify the HTTP address of the Jenkins installation, such as 
http://yourhost.yourdomain/jenkins/. This value is used to let Jenkins know how 
to refer to itself, ie. to display images or to create links in emails. This is 
necessary because Jenkins cannot reliably detect such a URL from within itself
```

so in your case: http://www.devportal.org:90/

That line should be probably removed as I think it's not needed:

`proxy_redirect      http://jenkins_ci:8080/ http://www.devportal.org:90/;`

And you should remove '/ci' from proxy pass like this

```
proxy_pass http://jenkins_ci:8080;
```

Comment: Well, thanks for the help.
As I have set the jenkins instance at /ci and the container is started with JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix /ci" (and it appears in the ps cmde result), I guess that the jenkins URL in the config should be :
`http://www.devportal.org:90/ci`

Nevertheless I have no progress applying what you have suggested.

I add another wrong behavior.
When disconnecting, I am redirected to www.devportal.org/ci.
The port number is lost.